# Variable product attributes

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, magento2.3

Magento 2.3

Is there a way you can change a products attributes depending on the choice of the first attribute.

For example... I have 3 types of curtain rails Straight, U Shaped and L Shaped each of these types come in different sizes ie U Shaped -> 500mm x 1000mm x 500mm and Straight -> 2000mm.

Or is the solution making 3 separate products U Shaped, L Shaped and Straight?

Comment: I think you're referring to dependent custom options, it is by default not available in Magento but you can get extensions for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a configurable product for this situation, in that you have to give two option first option to select curtain shape and second option for select size for that type of curtain.